# Check if an object exists in a Laravel View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm sending data to a Laravel view and it's possible for one of the object not to exist, because it gets no results from the database.

The problem is I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object` and I don't know how to check if the object exists directly in the view.

Here's some code to understand:

```
$segment = $request->segment(2);
$apk = Apk::where('slug', '=', $segment)->first(); 

$cat = Category::where('id', $apk->category_id)->first();
$parentcat = Category::where('id', $cat->parent)->first();
$related = Apk::where('category_id', $cat->id)
                ->where('id', '!=', $apk->id)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();

return view('single')->with('apk', $apk)->with('related', $related)->with('cat', $cat)->with('parentcat', $parentcat);
```

And the view:

```
@foreach ($related as $rel)
            <div class="item">
                <a href="{{ url('/apk/'.$rel->slug)}}">{{ $rel->name.' '.$rel->version }}</a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

It's possible for `$related` to be empty and that seems to cause the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you edit your question with code?

Comment: @User I've added it, I hope you can understand my problem from it.

Comment: try like this return $related in controller.

Comment: comment this line return view('single')...

Comment: I did it and it seems like there's another problem. It doesn't give an error when `$related` is empty.

Comment: are you getting any values from return $related???

Comment: how about you add a @if() statement before the @foreach() ? like @if(!empty($related)) @foreach(etc....) @endif..you can also set a check in the controller and set the $related variable to something before you include it into your view.

Comment: I've removed the `related` code entirely and it still doesn't work, so the problem must be elsewhere :)

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting, it should tell you which object you are trying to get a property of? this could be from $apk, $cat or $parentcat. Need proper error in order to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $related value is empty in controller.

try like this

```
$related = Apk::where('category_id', $cat->id)
                ->orWhere('id', '!=', $apk->id)
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get(); 

return $related;
```

first try like this if $related value return any thing we can push this object to view.

so first check the data coming from database or not.

Comment: It sometimes work when `$related` is empty. I'm getting the error sometimes when it's not empty. I've also removed the `related` code entirely and I'm still getting errors, so it must be something else.

Comment: try with $apk,$cat values put into return statements.

Comment: It's a problem with $cat and $parentcat. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@if($related)
    //foreach.....
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it that way:

```
if ( !empty ( $variable ) ) {
    ...
}
```